# Extract images from SWF using PHP

Tags: php, flash

I'm making an administrator panel to manage different SWF files.

To be able to administrate them with ease, I would like to extract one specific image from the SWF and display it. I've searched around for a while now and all the resources seems to be outdated or lacking information.

I've read about **SWFTools** but I couldn't find any examples on how to use it with PHP.

Comment: Do you have any current code you have tried or any errors it is giving?

Comment: Have you tried the SWFTools PHP package? You can find it here: https://github.com/alchemy-fr/PHPSwftools.

Comment: @gabe3886 I haven't tried anything, as most of the links I found were old and outdated.

Answer (score 0):

Best to my knowledge, you **can not** use PHP to decode a SWF file on the fly, SWF files are compiled flash containers.. you should source the images another way for a thumbnail or so and index them using PHP to show or when not.